# pip install : issue with the ssl certificate

Tags: python, linux, numpy, matplotlib, pip

I'm using Debian 9 and I have installed Python 3.6.2 and pip 9.0.1. Still, there is a problem when I want to install modules like numpy, scipy or matplotlib. I always get the following error when I use the pip install command:

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl
>   module in Python is not available. Collecting numpy   Could not fetch
>   URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem
>   confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the
>   SSL module is not available. - skipping   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for numpy

I tried the top answer of this subject ([pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)) but it didn't work. In fact, I get the same error message.

Unfortunately, this command was a fail as well.

> pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy --trusted-host pypi.python.org numpy

I hope someone will be able to solve my problem. Thanks in advance for your help. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Uncomment lines 209-212 in Python-3.6.2/Modules/Setup

   `SSL=/usr/local/ssl
   _ssl _ssl.c \
       -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
       -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto`
2. Make sure libssl-dev is installed
3. Go to your Python directory and do ./configure, make, and make install
4. Install packages with the following command: `pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org packageName`

Hope that helped someone. :D

Comment: How to fix the problem when you're on a corporate network where the proxy servers inject company certificate chain which is not trusted by Python?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following commands to resolve the issue

`$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py >> get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py`